# Concat two columns from different MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, concatenation, group-concat

I am trying to concat a list of usernames into one column in MySQL. The two lists of usernames are coming from two different tables.

```
(SELECT CAST(group_concat(CONCAT(usr.username, ' ' ,cc.username)separator ',') AS CHAR(200)) FROM messagejobrecipients mr
        LEFT JOIN chatusers cur on mr.ChatUserID = cur.ID 
        left join users usr on cur.TableUserID=usr.user_id
        left join customer_contacts cc on cur.TableUserID=cc.id
        WHERE JobID = j.ID) AS MembersIncluded
```

The code works fine if I just try to display `CONCAT(usr.username)` or `CONCAT(cc.username)` but when I try display both `CONCAT(usr.username, ' ' ,cc.username)` it always returns null.

Comment: try to remove group_concat and check, i guez group concat is creating issue. Also, where is group by clause in query ?

Comment: @Purushottamzende if I remove the group_concat I get the error `expected CHAR`. This is only part of the sql I am using group by. Like I said the sql works fine if I only try to concat one username but the issue is when I try contact the two usernames

Comment: create a sqlfiddle with about 10 rows max each table. I will look at it

Comment: @Drew ok I tried to create the sqlfiddle but nothing is showing when I click on run Run SQL - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a496c/1 but maybe this will still help to see how the tables are conncected

Comment: I will get back to it in a few minutes.

Comment: @Drew do you know what the problem is?

Comment: If you could get it down to a 3 table with 5 rows each left join with a concat I could spend the time. As it is now, I earmark 30 minutes on this one and I don't have that at the momen